# boost local_date_time: how to set a specific time information(hour, min and sec)

Tags: c++, datetime, boost

I have a question which is related to different timezone. There is a file storing a local start and end time. 
e.g. the first entry is in NY timezone while the second is in HK timezone.

```
80000-150000
100000-180000
```

So I try to use the boost::local_date_time to get the local current time by `local_sec_clock::local_time(poTimezone)` where `poTimezone` is `boost::local_time::time_zone_ptr`. Then set the hour, min and sec to this new object. However, I found there is no way to set that for local_date_time object. Is there anyone who have any idea on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `local_data_time`

A sample speaks more than a thousand words I guess:

```
#include <boost/date_time/local_time/local_time.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/local_time/local_time_io.hpp>
#include <boost/make_shared.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main() {

    namespace lt = boost::local_time;
    namespace pt = boost::posix_time;
    using   date = boost::gregorian::date;

    lt::tz_database db;
    db.load_from_file("/home/sehe/custom/boost/libs/date_time/data/date_time_zonespec.csv");

    //for (auto region : db.region_list()) std::cout << region << "\n";

    auto NY = db.time_zone_from_region("America/New_York");
    auto HK = db.time_zone_from_region("Asia/Hong_Kong");

    lt::local_date_time first (date {2015,1,1}, pt::time_duration{10,12,0}, NY, false);
    lt::local_date_time second(date {2015,1,1}, pt::time_duration{10,12,0}, HK, false);

    lt::local_time_period period(first, second);
    std::cout << "period: " << period << "\n";
    std::cout << "duration: " << period.length() << "\n";
}
```

Prints

```
period: [2015-Jan-01 10:12:00 EST/2015-Jan-01 10:11:59.999999 HKT]
duration: -13:00:00
```

See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d4da5343eb4a3383)** (without timezone database)

---

### Bonus

Two different ways to update time fields on an existing ldt:

```
first  = lt::local_date_time(first.date(),  pt::hours(7) +  pt::seconds(59), first.zone(),  first.is_dst());
//
second = lt::local_date_time(second.date(), pt::time_duration(7, 0, 59),     second.zone(), second.is_dst());
```

See it **[Live as well](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e332ab2b84c5c8ec)**

Comment: Thanks. I am not realize that it can be updated with time_duration.